# FortiClient headless cli - how to install and configure to handle certain IP ranges only or permit SSH

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, vpn

I am trying to configure the headless VPN only FortiClient on an AWS ubuntu 20.04 ec2 instance, and though I am able to connect to the target, I am then disconnected from the instance and cannot progress.

Setup:

```bsh
wget http://cdn.software-mirrors.com/forticlientsslvpn_linux_4.4.2328.tar.gz
tar -xzvf forticlientsslvpn_linux_4.4.2328.tar.gz
cd ./forticlientsslvpn/64bit/helper
sudo ./setup.linux.sh 
# Accept license
cd ..
./forticlientsslvpn_cli --server serveraddress:port --vpnuser username
# Enter password
##Connected!
```

At this stage, I am booted out of the instance and cannot reconnect (requiring a soft restart of the instance to gain access again)

I can see that there is a configuration file at `forticlientsslvpn/64bit/helper/config` but I cannot find any documentation describing what can be configured there or whether it is something I should be concerned with.

The CLI itself doesn't take any other options other than:

```
forticlientsslvpn_cli [--proxy proxyaddress:proxyport] --server vpnserveraddress:vpnport [--proxyuser proxyuser] [--vpnuser vpnuser] [--pkcs12 pkcs12path] [--keepalive]
```

**I would like to either:**

- Preserve my original SSH connection (and any future connections) so I can develop within the VPN or;
- Limit the VPN to only package traffic that is going to a specific IP range (CIDR block)

I have found three different methods for installing the client (`sudo apt install forticlient`, `sudo apt install -y openfortivpn`, `see above`) and cannot navigate through them. I have looked into [FortiClientLinuxGuide](https://fortinetweb.s3.amazonaws.com/docs.fortinet.com/v2/attachments/b195a357-50a9-11e9-94bf-00505692583a/FortiClient_%26_FortiClient_EMS_6.2.0_New_Features_Guide.pdf) and installed that tool but couldn't find out how to configure it as a VPN instead (or where to add the configuration). Similar experience with the second one.

This seems to be the only documentation about how to configure the CLI and its just the bear minimum [How to setup and install SSLVPN](https://community.fortinet.com/t5/FortiClient/Technical-Tip-How-to-install-and-configure-SSLVPN-client-in/ta-p/196863?externalID=FD39996).

**This post seems to be having the same problem** [ssh-telnet-disconnects](https://community.fortinet.com/t5/Fortinet-Forum/ssh-and-telnet-disconnect-after-about-15s/m-p/381?m=194995) and the solution looks like it would work if only I knew how to set that configuration.

**alternatively**, I have looked up **split tunnel** configuration which looks like it would be ideal but cannot work out how I would set that up. The documentation is only via the GUI [Enable-split-tunnel-feature](https://community.fortinet.com/t5/FortiGate/Technical-Tip-Enabling-split-tunnel-feature-for-SSL-VPN/ta-p/198108?externalID=FD46074)